# Magento1: Reindexing since one month Catalog URL Rewrite

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, reindex

in my magento 1.9.3.6 website one indexing is not done since last 45 days and still processing. 
And i am also unable to update and save product from admin panel.

Please suggest me any solution.
[image: catalog url rewrite]

Answer (score 0):

Please do the manual reindexing process after clearing the cache

Comment: i tried also that but not get any  success

Comment: does anyone have solution for this. i have also used reindexing using cron job. but still not problem solved. please tell me any solution

https://prnt.sc/jsee70